# ViewHolder and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I've got a problem with updating ListView with AsyncTask.

I use ViewHolders to improve performance, but they are causing problems with AsyncTask. As official android website says passing viewholder to asynctask is not a bad idea (http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) but in this case, when AsyncTask lasts long enough it updates two items at once with the same value.

I have an impression, that certain viewholder is used again 4-5 items further, and when asynctask does not finish work before passing again the same viewholder bug happens. After a while this viewholder is updating again and have correct value, but it's not satisfying me.

Is my way of thinking right? How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, Views are reused in ListView's.

So you you are starting an `AysncTask` in every `getView()`, multiple Tasks might run to load Data in the same View.
Bugs might occur especially while and after scrolling, if the Task take some time to finish.

**How to solve this?**

Basically you have to make sure, only one(the latest) Task is running for each View.
This can be done, by saving some kind of reference to the last Task in the View.
And if a new Task is started, you have to check for such a reference and cancel the old Task.

A pretty good description can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html).

The part "Handle Concurrency" should be most interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your system is set up. If you launch the AsyncTask when the view is requested, yes, your way of thinking is right. Otherwise, I couldn't tell you.

What you could do is add a boolean in your ViewHolder saying "locked". Set that one to true if you launch an AsyncTask, and let the AsyncTask set it to false when it's done. Before launching an AsyncTask, test if the locked boolean is set to false. That way you'll know not to launch another AsyncTask.